# Making International calls over the internet

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

Other than using Elastic SIP trunking, is there a twilio products that can enable me make two way calls over the internet? real time calls.

I've gone through the dashboard products, but the only thing I found that came close was SIP trunking, and that would require an addition infrastructure, IP-PBX.

Any other options I might have missed?

Comment: When you say real time calls over the Internet, do you mean with both parties using an application to make/receive calls or is one party on the PSTN (phone network) using a landline/mobile phone while the other is using an application?

Comment: @Alan Preferably both parties using an application to make/receive calls.    Otherwise using the PSTN. whichever does not require an additional infrastructure, just two phones and the application

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of options. There is the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for JavaScript, iOS, and Android, which leverages WebRTC to enable voice calling from within your web browser or by embedding the SDK directly into your mobile application. Here is the [Twilio Client Javascript Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart) guide. Two webRTC clients can communicate directly with each other (without going across the PSTN) by calling their identities but they can also make/receive calls to/from the PSTN.

The other option which works best from within North America, currently, is using a SIP end-point to register directly with Twilio's US1 data center, to make and receive calls. If two SIP end-points are registered to the same Twilio SIP Domain within your account, they can make calls with one-another without going across the PSTN and PSTN calling via SIP end-point is also available. The blog, [Registering a SIP Phone Directly to Twilio (and so much more...)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound), covers this.